# Appending an object more than once using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to write a very simple code of jquery to append an element. Here is an example code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var v=$("strong");
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){

                    $(".c1").append($ (v) );

            });
        });
</script>
```

What happens here, the content of `<div class="c1">` appears just once with multiple click. Instead of jQuery object, if I put html content then it appears as many as I click the button. I want to do the same thing with Object.

I started learning jQuery just today. So any sort of suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this line:

```
$(".c1").append(v.clone());
```

If you want it to append the same node multiple times you need to either dynamically create that node, or clone the existing one.

Comment: I'm afraid that loop is not working here. For example -  $("button").click(function(){
               for(x=1;x<=3;x++){
                    $(".c1").append($(".testDiv").clone());
                }
            }); ----------- here the div should appear 3 times. Instead, it's appearing 7 times. Any suggestion please?

Comment: because you are using $().clone() it will get all class="testDiv" on the page. If you want it to only use the ones that are there when the page loads make a variable, and myVariable.clone()